# IBM-MQ kubernetes helm chart ImagePullBackOff

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-helm, ibm-mq, helmfile

I want to deploy IBM-MQ to Kubernetes (Rancher) using helmfile. I've found this link and did everything as described in the guide: https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/ibm-charts/ibm-mqadvanced-server-dev.

But the pod is not starting with the error: "ImagePullBackOff". What could be the problem? My helmfile:

```
...
repositories:
  - name: ibm-stable-charts
    url: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IBM/charts/master/repo/stable

releases:
  - name: ibm-mq
    namespace: test
    createNamespace: true
    chart: ibm-stable-charts/ibm-mqadvanced-server-dev
    values:
      - ./ibm-mq.yaml
```

ibm-mq.yaml:

```
- - - 
license: accept
security:
  initVolumeAsRoot: true/false // I'm not sure about this, I added it just because it wasn't working.
// Both of the options don't work too 
queueManager:
  name: "QM1"
  dev:
    secret:
      adminPasswordKey: adminPassword
      name: mysecret
```

I've created the secret and seems like it's working, so the problem is not in the secret.
The full error I'm getting:

```
Failed to pull image "ibmcom/mq:9.1.5.0-r1": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: manifest for ibmcom/mq:9.1.5.0-r1 not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
```

I'm using helm 3, helmfile v.0.141.0, kubectl 1.22.2

Comment: can you show all the steps needed to reproduce this? I've tried to simply take your example in the questions and run "as is", but there are failures, obviously. So a _minimal_, _reproducible_ example would help greatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will leave some things as an exercise to you, but here is what that tutorial says:

```
helm repo add ibm-stable-charts https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IBM/charts/master/repo/stable
```

You don't really need to do this, since you are using `helmfile`.

Then they say to issue:

```
helm install --name foo 
     ibm-stable-charts/ibm-mqadvanced-server-dev 
     --set license=accept 
     --set queueManager.dev.secret.name=mysecret 
     --set queueManager.dev.secret.adminPasswordKey=adminPassword 
     --tls
```

which is targeted towards `helm2` (because of those `--name` and `--tls`), but that is irrelevant to the problem.

When I install this, I get the same issue:

> Failed to pull image "ibmcom/mq:9.1.5.0-r1": rpc error: code = NotFound desc = failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/ibmcom/mq:9.1.5.0-r1": failed to resolve reference "docker.io/ibmcom/mq:9.1.5.0-r1": docker.io/ibmcom/mq:9.1.5.0-r1: not found

I went to the docker.io page [of theirs](https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/mq/tags) and indeed such a tag : `9.1.5.0-r1` is not present.

OK, can we update the image then?

```
helm show values ibm-stable-charts/ibm-mqadvanced-server-dev
```

reveals:

```
image:
   # repository is the container repository to use, which must contain IBM MQ Advanced for Developers
  repository: ibmcom/mq
  # tag is the tag to use for the container repository
  tag: 9.1.5.0-r1
```

good, that means we can change it via an override value:

```
helm install foo 
   ibm-stable-charts/ibm-mqadvanced-server-dev 
   --set license=accept 
   --set queueManager.dev.secret.name=mysecret 
   --set queueManager.dev.secret.adminPasswordKey=adminPassword 
   --set image.tag=latest # or any other tag
```

so this works.

How to set-up that tag in `helmfile` is left as an exercise to you, but it's pretty trivial.

Comment: Yes, I already solved this and my solution is the same, but thanks, I will accept this as an answer